# connection to FireStore in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Could anyone please tell what is this error related to and how to fix it?

**Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.** (image)

I've done everything according to Google instructions in Gradle files and synchronized it, but it didn't help. Android Studio 4.2

[picture with an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb93G.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to fix `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}


allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

here you could replace `jcenter()` to `mavenCentral()`

also remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Its works for me